# Highcharts with shared and split tooptip, Is there any possible to style the hover xAxis labels?

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

**Expect**:
set my custom style on the xAxis labels, and cancel the 'default' style(see below fiddle) once hover out.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/syp7rvg5/)

**Tried**:

```
tooltip: {
  useHTML: true
}


.test {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Yes, I can set the style now, but the 'default' style can't be canceled, the default style 'stay' once `mouseover` happens especially on a narrow screen.

BTW, I did this to keep the tooltip with overwriting the `Highcharts.hide` function (Thanks to StackOverflow too):

```
    (function (H) {
        H.wrap(H.Tooltip.prototype, 'hide', function () {
        });
    }(Highcharts));
```

To visualize this problem with clear, I post some image:

[image: Screen Shot 2017-01-16 at 5.24.10 PM.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap `Highcharts.Tooltip.prototype.renderSplit(labels, points)` method and at the end overwrite the tooltip attributes.

```
Highcharts.wrap(Highcharts.Tooltip.prototype, 'renderSplit', function(p, labels, points) {
  p.call(this, labels, points);

  var tt = this.tt;

  if (tt) {
    // overwriting tooltip box attrs
    tt.attr({
      padding: 20,
      fill: 'red',
      stroke: 'blue',
      'stroke-width': 3,
      r: 4
    });

    // changing the position of the text inside the box
    tt.text.attr({
      y: 50
    })
  }
});
```

For changing text style, you can use [tooltip.headerFormat](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.area.tooltip.headerFormat) property.

```
tooltip: {
  split: true,
  headerFormat: '<span style="font-size: 30px; color: white">{point.key}</span>'
},
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/n903143x/

Comment: Thank bro, you save my life. To make better use of Highcharts, Maybe I need more knowledge on SVG. Thank you. How could I get more attribute about the `tt` except debugger and console from Chrome Tool, I didn't find any document about this.

Comment: Thank bro, you save my life. To make better use of Highcharts, Maybe I need more knowledge on SVG. Thank you. How could I get more attribute about the `tt` for example except for debugger and console from Chrome Tool, I didn't find any document about this.

Comment: Unfortunately you can learn it only by reading source code or trying to understand other people examples. On Highcharts website there is a user showcase which might be helpful too.