# How to create a Highcharts extension for an Angular 6 Component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, highcharts, definitelytyped

I want to be able to reposition the tooltip for a Highchart stock chart with the tooltip split option set to 'true'.

I am trying to get an effect similar to this demo in my component: http://jsfiddle.net/tbguemvL/

But using the Highcharts extension and plugin methods: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts

As suggested in this post:
[Highcharts with shared and split tooptip, Is there any possible to style the hover xAxis labels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41673027/highcharts-with-shared-and-split-tooptip-is-there-any-possible-to-style-the-hov)

The component is using the Highcharts Javascript library with the type definitions from DefinitelyTyped:

```
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import * as Highchart from 'highcharts/js/highcharts';
import * as HighchartMore from 'highcharts/js/highcharts-more';
import * as HighStockcharts from 'highcharts/highstock';
const HighChartsMore = HighchartMore(Highcharts);

...

public createChart(): HighchartMore {
    const highChart: HighchartMore = new HighStockcharts.StockChart(this.setInitialOptions());
    this.chartCreated.emit(highChart);
    return highChart;
}
```

While I am building up the options for my chart in `this.setInitialOptions()`, before the chart is created I tried calling this:

```
Highcharts.wrap(Highcharts.Tooltip.prototype, 'renderSplit', (p, labels, points) => {
  // Before the original function
  console.log('We are about to render a split tooltip!');

  // Now apply the original function with the original arguments,
  // which are sliced off this function's arguments
  p.call(this, labels, points);

  // Add some code after the original function
  console.log('We just finished rendering a split tooltip!');
});
```

This doesn't get called when the renderSplit method should fire.

How do I craft this wrap statement in a typescript Angular 6 component and where I would place the wrap code to get it to execute and extend the method?

Comment: Thank you Pawel!  I was calling it too late and from Highcharts instead of HighStockcharts which meant the proper chart was not picking it up.

Answer (score 0):

You should add your wrap before rendering chart, for example after this line: `const HighChartsMore = HighchartMore(Highcharts); Highcharts.wrap(...);`.

**Extras:**

You are loading Highcharts and Highstock -> it will cause errors. Highstock contains Highcharts, so no need to load Highcharts.